# Maps API for saved maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

With Google maps, we can save a private or Public map and add places and markers on it manually. Can we use Google Maps API v3 to programmatically add markers to such a map? This is so that when the map is displayed, all markers will be pre-loaded by Google.

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the Google Maps JavaScript API is very powerful. Please refer to the API reference to get started (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple).